# Inheritance unlock issue in CQ MSM

Tags: jsp, inheritance, aem, multisite

I have a header component within which I have wrapped 3 more components.When I roll-out the page, the new page's inheritance lock is such that when I unlock the top most component (i.e, the main header that wraps the remaining), even the ones under that are getting unlocked(inheritance cancelled) which I don't want to happen. Please suggest if there is any way to avoid this without a JSP work around. Please find the code below:

```
    <header class="header" role="header" id="header">   
     <div class="header_wrap">
      <div class="header_main">
        <div class="row">
        <cq:include path="./globalNav1" resourceType="component1" />
        <cq:include path="./globalNav2" resourceType="component2" />
        <cq:include path="./globalNav3" resourceType="component2" />
        </div   
      </div>
    </div>
   </header>
```

Comment: This is working as designed.